# Return vowels from word

Tags: prolog

I've got this work to do and my teacher gave me a prolog file with the following facts:

```
vowel(a).
vowel(e).
vowel(i).
vowel(o).
vowel(u).

consonant(b).
consonant(c).
consonant(d).
consonant(f).
consonant(g).
consonant(h).
consonant(j).
consonant(k).
consonant(l).
consonant(m).
consonant(n).
consonant(p).
consonant(q).
consonant(r).
consonant(s).
consonant(t).
consonant(v).
consonant(w).
consonant(x).
consonant(y).
consonant(z).
```

And I need to create a rule that is able to return the vowels. How can I do that?

The output would be something like this:

```
blafoo([s,a,r,a], X).
X = [a].
```

I can't use any prolog predicate.

Comment: If you cannot use any "prolog predicate" - I assume you mean built-in predicate or special control construct, then you have to use both consonant/1 and vowel/1!

Comment: I need to create the rules, but I must not use built-in predicates.

Comment: My answer blow just uses pure Prolog predicates. No built-ins at all!

Comment: Dont' remove `vowel/1` and `consonant/1`. Your question becomes meaningless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are mentioning both `vowel/1` and `consonant/1`, you might be expected to write a pure, monotonic version. After all, why do you mention `consonant/1`?

```
word_vowels([], []).
word_vowels([C|Xs], Vs) :-
   consonant(C),
   word_vowels(Xs, Vs).
word_vowels([V|Xs], [V|Vs]) :-
   vowel(V),
   word_vowels(Xs, Vs).

?- word_vowels([a,m,a,z,o,n],Vs).
   Vs = [a,a,o]
;  false.
```

Alternatively using [`tfilter/3`](/a/22053194/772868):

```
vowel_truth(C,true) :-
   vowel(C).
vowel_truth(V,false) :-
   consonant(V).

?- tfilter(vowel_truth,[a,m,a,z,o,n],Vs).
   Vs = [a,a,o]
;  false.
```

Comment: @SnakeSheet: So this is the solution you need!

Comment: Got that one right! Just need some help with another one, can you create a chat so I can explain you ?

Comment: @SnakeSheet: Not sure how this works. Just ask here, and we will be transferred automatically.

Comment: Ah ok, I have a rule to remove duplicates from a list and I call it here `word_vowels([C|Xs], R) :- consonant(C), word_vowels(Xs, Vs), distinct(Vs,R).`. If my list is `[a,n,a]` I get `X = [a,a]` if the list is `[n,a,n,a]` I get `X = [a]`.

Comment: @SnakeSheet: Don't use it within, for you would call distinct too often. Either call it before or after...

Comment: Where should I call it ?

Comment: Outside: `word_uniquevowels(Ws, Us) :- word_vowels(Ws,Vs), distinct(Vs,Us).`

Answer (score 2):

If your Prolog implements it, I would go with standard ISO sub_atom/5

```
 ?- W = amazon, sub_atom(W, _,1,_, C).
W = amazon,
C = a ;
W = amazon,
C = m ;
...
```

then

```
blafoo(Word, Wovel) :- sub_atom(Word, _,1,_, Wovel), vowel(Wovel).
```

*edit* after comment

Prolog doesn't 'returns' things, but you could always use a more appropriate naming and implementation for the relation, for instance like

```
word_vowels(Word, Wovels) :-
  findall(Wovel, (sub_atom(Word, _,1,_, Wovel), vowel(Wovel)), Wovels).
```

Comment: But I need to return only the vowels

Answer (score 2):

`setof/3` could be a good choice here:

```
?- setof(X,(member(X,[a,m,a,z,o,n]),vowel(X)),L).
L = [a, o].
```

Comment: And how can I divide that setof to various rules ?

Comment: @SnakeSheet what do you mean? you want to also get the consonants? for that: `setof(X,(member(X,[a,m,a,z,o,n]),consonant(X)),Consonants).` will give you `Consonants=[m,n,z].`.

Comment: I need to make a rule so I am able to just type "removevowels([s,a,r,a],X)." and return "X = [a]."

Comment: @SnakeSheet your `removevowels` is a weird name for a predicate that actually _keeps_ vowels. So let me rename is as `keepvowels`: `keepvowels(A,X) :- setof(V,(member(V,A),vowel(V),X).` should do.

Comment: My teacher said I can't use `setof`. In fact I can't use any prolog predicate.

Comment: @SnakeSheet then use false's recursive method. (You'll have to adapt it a bit to remove duplicates).

Comment: Can you explain me how I can do that ?

Comment: @SnakeSheet, ask false `;)`.