# How can I change this rule to work?

Tags: prolog

How can I remove `!` from this rule for it to work properly ?

```
extractvowels([],[]).
extractvowels([H|T],R):-consonant(H),extractvowels(S,R),!.
extractvowels([H|T],[H|R]):-extractvowels(S,R),!.
```

`consonant(H)` contains all the consonants.

And how can I join this rule(`distinct`) within the `extractvowels` one ?

```
member(X, [X|_]).      
member(X, [_|Tail]) :- member(X, Tail).

distinct([],[]).
distinct([H|T],C) :- member(H,T), distinct(T,C),!.
distinct([H|T],[H|C]) :- distinct(T,C).
```

I can't use any prolog predicate.

Comment: Perhaps not your problem, but definitely one you'll soon encounter -- prolog variable names are uppercase, so unless extractvowels is a procedure innate to swi, which I doubt, it should be capitalised.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return vowels from word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930118/return-vowels-from-word)

Comment: There is nothing specific to SWI-Prolog in your question!

Comment: It's the program I'm using.

Comment: @SnakeSheet: That's fine, but it is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't address directly your question, already answered by Sergey, rather suggest a 'programming style' that attempt to avoid 'boilerplate' code, and - sometimes - cuts.

Consider this simple query - it's plain Prolog (apart the extended string notation, `hello world`, SWI-Prolog specific) , and can 'solve in a line':

```
?- S=`hello world`, findall(C, (member(C, S), C > 0'a, C =< 0'z, \+ memberchk(C, `eiou`)), Cs), format('~s~n', [Cs]).
hllwrld
S = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114|...],
Cs = [104, 108, 108, 119, 114, 108, 100].
```

What's interesting to note: see how member/2 inside findall/3 acts as a lambda expression *and* search space generator, allowing to name the variable - we can call it the 'local environment' - and then allowing what Prolog play best - clause solving.

General and easy, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
extractvowels([], []).
extractvowels([H|T], R) :- consonant(H), extractvowels(T, R).
extractvowels([H|T],[H|R]) :- \+ consonant(H), extractvowels(T, R).
```

I fixed your singleton variables 'S' - changed to 'T' (SWI-Prolog probably complained about this, and you should fix any singleton variables warnings).

You last `extractvowels` cut ('!') could be just removed - a cut at the end of the last clause does nothing.

To get rid of the first cut I added a "guard" rule `\+ consonant(H)` to the last `extractvowels` clause - proceed only if H is not a consonant.

Comment: This predicate also lends itself well to avoiding the extra "guard" rule via a single, recursive clause using an if-then-else construct.

Comment: And whats means "\+" ? And How can I "call" the distinct rule so for example if I have this list [s,a,r,a] the extract vowels would be [a,a] and with the distinct with would be just [a], how can that be made ?

Comment: @SnakeSheet have you looked at a Prolog manual? The `\+` operator is described there. As far as how to do the `distinct`, you must remember Prolog is a logic language. So you'd just follow one rule with another: `extractvowels(A, B), distinct(B, C).` In Prolog, `,` is a logical conjunction.

Comment: something like this ?
"extractvowels([H|T], R) :- consonant(H), extractvowels(T, K), distinct(K, R)." and 
"extractvowels([H|T],[H|R]) :- \+ consonant(H), extractvowels(T, K), distinct(K, R)." ? If I do like that I get this awkward result
"?- extractvowels([s,a,r,a],X).
X = [a] ."

"?- extractvowels([a,m,a,z,o,n],X).
X = [a, a, o] ."

Comment: My teacher said I can't use `\+`. In fact I can't use any prolog predicate.

Comment: From the previous instance of this question I see that you have `vowel/1` defined - so simply change `\+ consonant(H)` to `vowel(H)`.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your definition of "vowel" is "that which is not a consonant" (there are lots of characters, most of which are neither vowels, nor consonants), and if by "extract vowels", you mean

> remove all the vowels, leaving only the consonants

then something like this  would work:

```
consonants_in( []     , []    ) .
consonants_in( [X|Xs] , [X|R] ) :-    consonant(X) , consonants_in(Xs,R) .
consonants_in( [X|Xs] , R     ) :- \+ consonant(X) , consonants_in(Xs,R) .
```

You could also say something like:

```
consonants_in( [] , [] ) .
consonants_in( [X|Xs] , R ) :-
  ( consonant(X) -> R = [X|R1] ; R = R1 ) ,
  consonants_in( Xs , R1 )
  .
```

If on the other hand, if by "*extract vowels*" , you mean

> remove all the consonants, leaving only the vowels

then you want the inverse, something like

```
vowels_in( []     , []    ) .
vowels_in( [X|Xs] , [X|R] ) :- \+ consonant(X) , vowels_in(Xs,R) .
vowels_in( [X|Xs] , R     ) :-    consonant(X) , vowels_in(Xs,R) .
```

or

```
vowels_in( [] , [] ) .
vowels_in( [X|Xs] , R ) :-
  ( consonant(X) -> R = R1 ; R = [X|R1] ) ,
  vowels_in( Xs , R1 )
  .
```

You could make things more declarative by making your definition of "vowel" explicit:

```
vowel(C) :- \+ consonant(C) .
```

and change your predicates accordingly:

```
vowels_in( []     , []    ) .
vowels_in( [X|Xs] , [X|R] ) :- vowel(X)    , vowels_in(Xs,R) .
vowels_in( [X|Xs] , R     ) :- \+ vowel(X) , vowels_in(Xs,R) .
```

or

```
vowels_in( [] , [] ) .
vowels_in( [X|Xs] , R ) :-
  ( vowel(X) -> R = [X|R1] ; R = R1 ) ,
  vowels_in( Xs , R1 )
  .
```

The advantage of this is that you could modify you definition of "vowel" later to be more correct,

```
vowel(a).
vowel(e).
vowel(i).
vowel(o).
vowel(u).
```

without affecting the rest or your code:

Comment: My rules work fine, I just need a way to redo them without `!` and `\+`, and not using any built-in predicate.

Comment: @SnakeSheet how is it that your rules work fine? They way you have them stated in your problem statement, you have a singleton variable, `S` in your `extractvowels` predicate which is problematic and the rules won't do what's expected.